# Defining Namespaces in code

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there a way to only define your parent namespace with out having to define all the children as well?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean. Please give examples.

Comment: Please elaborate on this question.

Comment: Are you talking about if you can `using` statements? eg. `using System` instead of `using System.IO`?

Comment: Do you mean, "can I have child namespaces without having to include them via using statements?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you are referring to something like the Java language that supports:

```
imports Java.AWT.*
```

As far as I know the * in the above statement is a wild-card so you don't have to define every method in the namespace.

In .net the various libraries are grouped together by namespaces and some of them appear to be subsets but I don't think they are actually represented as a heirarchy internally.

So for example if you wanted to use the StringBuilder class you would add in:

```
using System.Text;
```

but if you then wanted use Regular Expressions you would also add in

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Visual Studio has pretty good detection of this kind of thing so as long as you typed in a class name that is inside one of the libraries like

```
Regex reg = new Regex();
```

then after you had typed the first `Regex` you would be able to right click on it and choose the Resolve menu to either make it fully qualified like

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex reg = new Regex();
```

or add a using statement at the top (as demonstrated above)

Comment: A better question would've included "In Java i do this...  Do I need to do this in .Net"

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that's not possible.
When you include a namespace you have access ONLY to classes belonging to that namespace. There is no instruction to include in "cascade" child namespaces in the hierarchy.

Comment: In JAVA you can define (using) a parent namespace and all the children can be referenced as well.

I wanted to avoid the:
using Parent;
using Parent.Child1;
...etc

Thanks for the reply

Comment: @Arnej65: I'm afraid there is nothing like that in .NET :-(